# Issue while executing PostgreSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: postgresql

I am facing an issue while running executing the Postgresql StoredProcedure. When i am running Function , i am getting proper response but when i am running Stored Procedure i am getting this exception.

```
SQL State: 42883
ERROR: function abc_acclvl_proc(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 15org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function abc_acclvl_proc(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 15
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.executeWithFlags(PgCallableStatement.java:83)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
at macd.bean.MacdApp.FunctionReturnString.main(FunctionReturnString.java:37)
```

My Java code is :

```
public class FunctionReturnString {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String runFunction ="{call abc_acclvl_proc(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/maald?currentSchema=abc", "maald", "maald");
         Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
         CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(runFunction)) {
        
        
        callableStatement.setString(1, "Middletown");
        callableStatement.setString(2, "NJ");
        callableStatement.setString(3, "");
        callableStatement.setString(4, "Empty");
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.INTEGER);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, Types.INTEGER);
        boolean hasResultSet = callableStatement.execute();
        
        int result = callableStatement.getInt(5);

    
        System.out.println(result);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

My question is in the exception why i am getting "function macd_acclvl_proc(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist" . But it is a stored procedure in PostgreSQL server. PostgreSQL server version is 12.3 and as per PostgreSQL blog version higher than 11 does support Stored Procedure also. I am using postgresql-42.2.18 jar for connectivity.

My stored procedure definition is as belows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc.abc_acclvl_proc(
icity character,
istate character,
prodtype character,
ordgrp character,
INOUT cclvl bigint,
INOUT prlvl bigint)
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Any help will be appreciable. Thanks !!!

Comment: There is no schema qualification in the error message. Looks like the query gets executed without mentioning the correct schema.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. Since the parameters are defined as `INOUT`, you have to specify an input vale for them as well. If you don't use that value, you could use NULL.
2. By default, the JDBC driver will try to call a function and not a procedure.

   As specified in [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html), you would have to set `escapeSyntaxCallMode=call` when you establish the connection.

Here is a complete working sample:

```java
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:test?user=myuser&password=mypassword&escapeSyntaxCallMode=call");

java.sql.CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call abc.abc_acclvl_proc(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");

callableStatement.setString(1, "Middletown");
callableStatement.setString(2, "NJ");
callableStatement.setString(3, "");
callableStatement.setString(4, "Empty");
callableStatement.setInt(5, 0);
callableStatement.setInt(6, 0);

callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);

callableStatement.execute();
       
long result = callableStatement.getLong(5);

System.out.println(result);

conn.close();
```

Comment: I tried with escapeSyntaxCallMode=call but still getting same issue

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe for your information . But my stored procedure has cursor and it has isopen function , that doesn't support in PostgreSQL . So now while executing the stored procedure i'm getting issue related to cursor.
Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: There is nothing like that in your question. Perhaps you should ask another question with your cursor problem.

Comment: Yes Sure .. Thanks @ Laurenz Albe

Comment: It took me a good while to figure out I was missing `escapeSyntaxCallMode`. I added `escapeSyntaxCallMode=callIfNoReturn` to my connection string and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed don't have such a procedure. You are trying to call a procedure with the signature `abc_acclvl_proc(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying)`

However your procedure is defined as `abc_acclvl_proc(character, character, character, character)`

This is the same as if you were trying to call a function in Java defined as `foo(char)` with a `String` parameter.

You should change your procedure definition to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc.abc_acclvl_proc(
  icity varchar,
  istate varchar,
  prodtype varchar,
  ordgrp varchar,
  INOUT cclvl bigint,
  INOUT prlvl bigint)
language plpgsql;
```

In general the use of the `char` (or `character`) data type is [strongly discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)